# Trying to prove that a type is an instance of `euclidean_semiring` (in Isabelle)

Tags: types, isabelle

I am using the Nonstandard_Analysis session in Isabelle/HOL, and I am trying to prove that the type `'a::euclidean_semiring star` is an instance of `euclidean_semiring`.

I am showing

```
instance star ::  (euclidean_semiring) euclidean_semiring
proof (intro_classes)
  show "euclidean_size (0::'a star) = (0::nat)"
```

but get the following error

```
  No type arity star :: euclidean_semiring
```

even when just stating the required goal statements. Seems like a bit of a catch-22. `euclidean_semiring` is specified as follows

```
  class euclidean_semiring = semidom_modulo + 
   fixes euclidean_size :: "'a ⇒ nat"
   assumes size_0 [simp]: "euclidean_size 0 = 0"
   assumes mod_size_less: 
     "b ≠ 0 ⟹ euclidean_size (a mod b) < euclidean_size b"
   assumes size_mult_mono:
     "b ≠ 0 ⟹ euclidean_size a ≤ euclidean_size (a * b)"
```

and I have already shown

```
instance star :: (semidom_modulo) semidom_modulo
```

Actually I am wondering if the reason this particular example is giving an error, even though I have been able to show similar things such as `instance star :: (semiring_parity) semiring_parity` is because this particular type-class `euclidean_semiring` has a parameter, namely `euclidean_size`.

Of course, I would most prefer a better explanation of the error message and a suggested workaround (if possible), but it would also be helpful to see examples of proving things of the form

```
  instance X :: (Y) Y
```

especially when `Y` is a type-class which takes a parameter, just as `euclidean_semiring` does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if the type class has parameters you have to do use `instantiation` and give definitions for them.

```
    instantiation star :: (euclidean_semiring) euclidean_semiring
    begin

    definition euclidean_size_star where
      "euclidean_size_star x = …"
      
    instance proof (intro_classes)
      …
    qed

    end
```

You can find examples for this anywhere in the library where `instantiation` is used, e.g. the instantiation of `euclidean_semiring` for `nat`.

Comment: Oh I see! I didn't really understand the difference between the two (instance and instantiation) because I found the tutorial on type classes confusing.

Comment: Do you know where I can find the example for nat? I searched the first few theories which depend on Euclidean_Division. Maybe nat is not explicitly proved to be an instantiation of euclidean_semiring but instead inherits it from being proved part of some other type class?

Comment: Oh I found instantiation nat :: unique_euclidean_semiring so I think my idea that nat is not explicitly proved as euclidean_semiring was right (and my question is answered).